# Copy a file to multiple folders with specific name (Automator or script)

Tags: macos, shell, replace, copy, automator

I want to replace a specific file eg. file.js which is located in different folderstructures but always in the same folder named "core" by another file with the same name.

Example: copy "file.js" to all "core" folders which are in different subfolders of a folder

Example:

from:

```
x1 / file.js
```

to:

```
x / a / a1 / a3 / core /file.js

x / b / b1 / core / file.js
```

I tried a solution in automator on osx, but I didn't manage to store a filepath of the core folders or to copy the file to a path variable.

Does anyone know a solution?

shell script or automator or any other automated solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it as a `bash` script but test it on a copy of temporary data first:

```
find . -name core -type d -execdir bash -c 'cd core && [ -f file.js ] && cp SOMENEWFILE .' \;
```

Replace the `cp SOMENEWFILE .` with `pwd` to test and see which directories it *would* copy to.

Comment: Oh wow mark thank you so much for your fast answer. everything behaved as expected, i'm so thankful =) sorry if comments are not thought for that kind of comment ^^ now i want to learn more about bash scripts :o)

Comment: hey mark, one question about this part: [ -f file.js ] 
i wanted to put the whole command in an automator shell script but it doesn't work. i assume that this is the problem..

what i am doing (trying to do) is: [ -f "$1" ] 
so i'm accessing the automator variable instead of writing the filename into the conditional.. but it doesnt work.. any idea?